# Given a sample space $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and $2$ random variables on this sample space. How do I determine if they are independent?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, random-variables, independence

### Question:

Given $2$ random variables $X,Y$ on some measurable space defined by $( \Omega = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\} , 2^\Omega )$ where the probability of an outcome $\Bbb{P}(\omega) = 1/6\ \forall \omega \in \Omega$.

$X(\omega) = \max( \omega , 5 )$

$Y(\omega) = \left\vert \omega - \frac{7}{2} \right\vert$

Are the random variables $X$ and $Y$ independent? (No is my answer)

### My Comments:

My main issue is that I am new to this kind of mathematics, and would like to have someone validate the logic and reasoning I used to get to this conclusion.

### My Work:

By definition of sigma algebra generated on a set:

$$\sigma(X) = \{ \{\} , \Omega , \{1,2,3,4,5\} , \{6\} \}$$

Similarly, for $\sigma(Y)$:

$$\sigma(Y) = \sigma( \{1,6\} , \{2,5\} , \{3,4\} )\\ = \{ \{\} , \Omega , \{1,6\} , \{2,5\} , \{3,4\} , \{2,3,4,5\} , \{1,3,4,6\} , \{1,2,5,6\} \}$$

Lets check the independence between $\sigma(X)$ and $\sigma(Y)$. Looking at the sets in $\sigma(X)$:

1. $\Bbb{P}( \{\} ) = 0$ by definition, and the intersection of any set with the empty set is empty so: Let $Y_i$ be any set in $\sigma(Y)$, then:

   $$\Bbb{P}( \{\} ) * \Bbb{P}( Y_i ) = 0 * \Bbb{P}( Y_i ) = 0\\\Bbb{P}( \{\} \cap Y_i ) = \Bbb{P}( \{\} ) = 0$$

   Therefore, $\Bbb{P}( \{\} ) * \Bbb{P}( Y_i ) = \Bbb{P}( \{\} \cap Y_i )$ , shows that $\{\}$ is independent of all sets in $\sigma(Y)$
2. $\Bbb{P}( \Omega ) = 1$ by definition, and the intersection of any set with the universal set is itself so: Let $Y_i$ be any set in $\sigma(Y)$, then:

   $$\Bbb{P}( \Omega ) * \Bbb{P}( Y_i ) = 1 * \Bbb{P}( Y_i ) = \Bbb{P}( Y_i )\\\Bbb{P}( \Omega \cap Y_i ) = \Bbb{P}( Y_i )$$

   Therefore, $\Bbb{P}( \Omega ) * \Bbb{P}( Y_i ) = \Bbb{P}( \Omega \cap Y_i )$ , shows that $\Omega$ is independent of all sets in $\sigma(Y)$
3. $\Bbb{P}( \{1,2,3,4,5\} ) = \frac{5}{6}$ since this set contains $5$ outcomes $\omega$ each with probability $\frac{1}{6}$. Independence with $\{\}$ and $\Omega$ follow from the previous $2$ arguments, so we will compare against the other sets in $\sigma(Y)$.

   $$\Bbb{P}( \{1,2,3,4,5\} ) * \Bbb{P}( \{1,6\} ) = \frac{5}{6} * \frac{2}{6} = \frac{10}{36}\\\Bbb{P}( \{1,2,3,4,5\} \cap \{1,6\} ) = \Bbb{P}( \{1\} ) = \frac{1}{6}$$

Since $\Bbb{P}( \{1,2,3,4,5\} ) * \Bbb{P}( \{1,6\} ) \ne \Bbb{P}( \{1,2,3,4,5\} \cap \{1,6\} )$, we can conclude that not all sets in $\sigma(X)$ are independent of every set in $\sigma(Y)$. Therefore, $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Next time could you use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your questions? That way we can understand your question more easily.

Comment: Thank you for the link Aiden, I have made the appropriate edits to the text such that it may be more readable.

Comment: As a matter of taste, i would have taken $A=\{6\}=X^{-1}(6)\in\sigma(X)$ and $B=\{3,4\}=Y^{-1}(1/2)\in\sigma(Y)$, and of course $0=\Bbb P(A\cap B)\ne\Bbb P(A)\cdot\Bbb P(B)$. Everything is ok, of course.